# ¿Cómo creo una funcion para construir un objeto en php y una funcion de guardado?

Tags: php

Intenté lo siguiente, pero no funcionó.

Necesito crear una función para crear el objeto con los parámetros `POST` del formulario. También una función para guardarlos luego en una base de datos:

```php
<?php 
$nombre_categoria = trim ($_POST['Categoria']);
$id_categoria = trim ($_POST['ID']);
    
/*echo "$nombre_categoria";
echo "$id_categoria";
echo "Hello";*/
    
class Categorias {      

  function __construct($id_categoria, $nombre_categoria)
  {
    $this-> id_articulo = $id_categoria;
    $this-> nombre_categoria = $nombre_categoria;
  }

}

function crear_categoria($id_categoria, $nombre_categoria) {
    $objeto= new Categorias($id_categoria, $nombre_categoria);
    return $objeto;
}
$objeto = crear_categoria($id_categoria, $nombre_categoria);
               
echo $objeto;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar debo decir que con esto estás intentando re-inventar la rueda, pues existen herramientas o librerías para mapear con suma facilidad datos recibidos (por $_POST o de otro modo) a clases del modelo de datos, asegurando el filtrado y la seguridad y otras cosas que, de otro modo, tendrás que garantizar tú mismo.

Otro dato importante es el nivel de encapsulación que quieres para las propiedades de la clase. Una solución fácil sugerirá que declares las propiedades de la clase como `public`, y que luego recorras un array asignando cada propiedad sin más. Pero ahí los campos de tu clase no quedan encapsulados, pudiendo ser modificados directamente sin pasar por métodos específicos (los llamados métodos *setter*).

Una cosa **muy importante es la coherencia**, tanto si te decides por re-inventar la rueda, como si te decides por alguna herramienta. Me refiero a que si en el  modelo de datos tienes una tabla `Categoria` con dos columnas: `id` y `nombre`, uses `id`  y `nombre` en **todas partes**, ya veremos, en la práctica, por qué (en la mayoría de herramientas ya existentes, puedes resolver cualquier divergencia con una anotación, pero eso no viene al caso ahora).

Dicho eso, asumimos que tienes una clase llamada `Categoria` (por lo general las clases se ponen en singular, no en plural, salvo excepciones). Para ampliar el ejemplo, veremos también el caso de una clase `Libro`. Y crearemos una clase utilitaria llamada `MapObject` que nos servirá para mapear datos a ambas clases indistintamente.

En el contexto donde recibes el `$_POST` tú podrás hacer algo como esto:

```
$oneCategory=MapObject::map(new Categoria(),$_POST);
```

Y `$oneCategory` será una instancia de `Categoria` con sus propiedades.

O podrás hacer esto:

```
$oneBook=MapObject::map(new Libro(),$_POST);
```

Y `$oneBook` será una instancia de `Libro` con sus propiedades.

La clave de todo, como dije antes, estará **en la coherencia**. porque desde el método `map`, en base a esa coherencia, setearemos las propiedades por sus nombres, respetando además la encapsulación (observa que los campos se declaran como `private` en las clases). Esa **coherencia** por supuesto, hace que **en el formulario asignes a cada `input` el `name` que tiene cada cosa en el modelo de datos**.

#### Código [<kbd>`VER DEMO`</kbd>](https://rextester.com/KVDP43798)

**Clase `Categoria`**

```
class Categoria 
{
    
    private $id;
    private $nombre;
    
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id=$id;
    }

    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
    }        
}
```

---

**Clase `Libro`**

```
class Libro 
{
    
    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id=$id;
    }

    public function setTitulo($titulo)
    {
        $this->titulo=$titulo;
    }        
}
```

---

**Clase `MapObject`** para mapear objetos de cualquier tipo

```
class MapObject
{
    public static function map ($obj = NULL, $data)
    {
        
        if(!is_object($obj)) {
            $obj = new StdClass ();
        }
        
        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            /*
                Convendría establecer una política de filtrado
                dependiendo del uso que quieras dar a los datos
                Aquí estaríamos invocando el setter de cada propiedad
                y asignándole el valor.
                La coherencia exige que cada clase tenga su setter
                respetando además la convención de nombre propia de los métodos
            */
            $obj->{'set'.ucwords($field)}(trim($value));
        }
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

---

**Uso contextual**

Simularemos un contexto en que recibes un `$_POST` de `Categoria` y otro de `Libro`.

```
$_POST=array('id'=>1,'nombre'=>'Prueba Categoría');
$oneCategory=MapObject::map(new Categoria(),$_POST);
var_dump($oneCategory);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(Categoria)#1 (2) {
  ["id":"Categoria":private]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["nombre":"Categoria":private]=>
  string(17) "Prueba Categoría"
}
```

---

```
$_POST=array('id'=>1,'titulo'=>'Prueba Libro');
$oneBook=MapObject::map(new Libro(),$_POST);
var_dump($oneBook);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(Libro)#2 (2) {
  ["id":"Libro":private]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["titulo":"Libro":private]=>
  string(12) "Prueba Libro"
}
```